# Meeting went horrible. Tech Lead thinks I wasn't well prepared

Tags: meetings, teamwork

I scheduled a meeting with the PO *(Product Owner)* and some other people in my team including my tech lead. PO asked some questions here and there about the issue that we're discussing. Some of them were QA related actual output results of the functionality.

When those questions were asked by the PO I redirected them to the QA person. But he just bounced them back to me. This has noted by the Tech lead as I wasn't well prepared for the meeting. In fact, I was well prepared and even came up with a uml diagram about the problem.

This seems to be a black mark on me. My yearly evaluation is at the end of this month. I am the developer who looked into this issue. *(Another developer has fixed half of the issue, that developer is now in a different team)* QA is a senior person.

**Question :** Should I send an email personally to the tech lead justifying that I was well prepared? That the QA was in lack of knowledge about the context that we were talking about?

*QA person is sitting next to me. Tech lead and QA are closer than me and the Tech lead.*

Comment: The QA person didn't know something, and you didn't know it either. For me this sounds like you both were not prepared. Don't blame someone else for it. (You had a single diagram? So what?)

Comment: But this feels something unfair has happened to me. Because the test result outputs has to be known by the QA. Yes dev must have some idea. But QA should be more confident with it. *As per my perspective*

Comment: There is no context here so it's impossible to know what the expectations were - as far as I can see a question was asked and nobody knew the answer, so the next step is to clarify that point. No big deal.

Comment: **So what's your question?**

Answer (score 2):

QA test results are partly communication from QA to development. I would expect both the QA person and the developer working a problem to be familiar with the relevant results. That is especially important at a meeting to discuss the bug, but is also part of fully understanding the bug. You should be able to discuss how the bug reports relate to the internal structure of the program, including your UML diagram. Is your current plan going to fully fix all the symptoms? If so, why?

The QA person's lack of preparation is presumably a problem for their supervisor. Your tech lead can do little or nothing about that. Your lack of preparation is a problem for your tech lead, and one the tech lead is trying to fix.

> Question : Should I want to send an email personally to the tech lead
>   justifying that I was well prepared. That QA was in lack of knowledge
>   about the context that we were talking about?

You were not well prepared because you could not answer questions about the reports characterizing the bug. That the QA person should also have been able to discuss the reports is irrelevant.

Especially given your upcoming yearly evaluation, you want the tech lead to stop thinking about the issue. That most likely to happen if the tech lead believes you will be better prepared in the future. It might be useful to tell the tech lead that you will make sure you can answer questions about the bug reports in any similar meetings, and perhaps ask for tips on other things you should prepare before meetings.

Sending e-mail suggesting that only the QA person needed to know about the reports will keep the issue in the tech lead's mind without the tech lead believing you will do any more to prepare for meetings in the future. That is counter-productive. Even simply dropping the issue would be better.

Comment: I agree, keep your head down, you weren't prepared and shouldn't have scheduled the meeting in the first place.